# Getting the mean by grouping every X number of rows and then the mean of next Y- number of rows

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas Dataframe:

```
   col1  
 0   1 
 1   1
 3   1
 4   2
 5   2
 6   1
 7   1
 8   1
 9   2
10   2
```

and a variables:

```
x = 3
y = 2
```

I want to transform it to another Dataframe by grouping first on X number of rows. calculate the mean and then group on the next y number of rows, calculate the mean and so on. The result from the df above should be:

```
   col1  
 0   1 
 1   2
 3   1
 4   2
```

Comment: Is it a coincidence that x and y equal the size of the sequence of 1s and 2s?

Comment: yes, it's just an example

Answer (score 0):

Check with np.put , then we using `diff` and `cumsum` create the group key

```
df['new']=0
np.put(df['new'],np.arange(len(df)),x*[1]+y*[2])
df.groupby(df.new.diff().ne(0).cumsum()).col1.mean()
Out[588]: 
new
1    1
2    2
3    1
4    2
Name: col1, dtype: int64
```